# UITableViewCell does not display content until tapped / Two cells on same row

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is a bug I just solved and I wanted to share it with the community because when searching I found no answers online and anyone I asked would reply with "hmmm interesting..." but have no idea what was going on.

At first glance I had a tableView that had some cells displayed and some cells which were just blank. When I tapped on a blank cell the content would then display (but not until a tap).

First thought: it's a data issue and tapping the cell is reloading it. I attempted to reload the data and even the individual rows after the tableView had been created and loaded but this did not resolve the problem. I also attempted to dispatch this call to the main queue and to call `setNeedsLayout` on the missing/blank indexPaths

The problem: I looked in view debugger and I discovered that the two blank cells actually did exist and they looked like they should look but they had a blank cell *on top of them*. That's right, there were TWO cells on one row, one on top of the other.

[image]

For those curious about the cell showing when it was tapped, I still do not know why this is such but if I tapped the cell the blank cell would go behind. There would still be two cells but I could now see the custom cell because the blank cell was behind it.

- `numberOfCellsInRow` was returning the correct number, 4
- view debugger showed 6 (4 rows where two of the rows contained two cells)
- viewing memory graph hierarchy in view debugger confirmed there were 6 cells on this table

I looked at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it looked alright though I noticed that UITableViewCell (generic type) was being used. The thing that was curious to me is that this was the same set up that was used on another view controller (`secondVC`) where there were no issues. After some time I noticed a difference.

This is the general pattern which was on `firstVC`. It was "customCell" that was covered by the blank UITableViewCell, and "genericCell" was a standard UITableViewCell on the storyboard

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let genericCell = tableView.dequeReusableCell(withIdentifier: "genericCell")
    if indexPath = IndexPath(row:0, section:0) {
         if let customCell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell") as? MyCustomCell {
        return customCell
        }
    } else if indexPath = IndexPath(row:1, section:0) {
        genericCell.titleLabel.text = "cell1"
    } else if indexPath = IndexPath(row:2, section: 0) {
        genericCell.titleLabel.text = "cell2"
    }

    return genericCell
}
```

Now what was different on `secondVC` is the first line:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let genericCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "genericCell")
    if indexPath = IndexPath(row:0, section:0) {......
```

I'm still not sure if this is an iOS/Xcode bug or if there is a logical explanation for this but the solution is to create "genericCell" only after the customCells are created and returned, like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath = IndexPath(row:0, section:0) {
         if let customCell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell") as? MyCustomCell {
        return customCell
        }
    } else {
        let genericCell = tableView.dequeReusableCell(withIdentifier: "genericCell")
        if indexPath = IndexPath(row:1, section:0) {
            genericCell.titleLabel.text = "cell1"
        } else if indexPath = IndexPath(row:2, section: 0) {
            genericCell.titleLabel.text = "cell2"
        }
        return genericCell
    }
}
```

or to create the UITableViewCell via an init method rather than dequeueing it from the storyboard -- as that worked without bugs on `secondVC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure if this is an iOS/Xcode bug or if there is a logical explanation for this but the solution is to create "genericCell" only after the customCells are created and returned, like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath = IndexPath(row:0, section:0) {
         if let customCell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell") as? MyCustomCell {
        return customCell
        }
    } else {
        let genericCell = tableView.dequeReusableCell(withIdentifier: "genericCell")
        if indexPath = IndexPath(row:1, section:0) {
            genericCell.titleLabel.text = "cell1"
        } else if indexPath = IndexPath(row:2, section: 0) {
            genericCell.titleLabel.text = "cell2"
        }
        return genericCell
    }
}
```

or to create the UITableViewCell via an init method rather than dequeueing it from the storyboard -- as that worked without bugs on `secondVC`.

If anyone has an explanation for why this is needed please post as an answer and I'm happy to make your answer as the accepted one!